# Connecting edges of picture in python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I have an image of a map.  I would like to make the left and right (East and west) edges of the map connect so that you can scroll forever to the right or left and keep scrolling over the same picture.  I've looked around and can't find anything on the topic (likely because I don't know what to call it).  I would also like to have the picture in a frame that I can grab and drag to move the picture around.  I was trying to do this in Tkinter, but I have a feeling there are probably easier ways to do this.

Comment: how do you want to implement this infinite scrolling? By clicking and dragging the mouse, similar to how google maps works? Or, do you expect to have left/right buttons that moves one image out and another one in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the results I wanted with pygame.

blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect

I setup a rectangle twice the width of my map, and set up a function to always have two maps drawn side by side.  I added functions to move the map as a % of the tile width.

```
SCREENRECT = Rect(0, 0, 6025, 3010)
...
class Arena:
    speed = 15
    def __init__(self):
        w = SCREENRECT.width
        h = SCREENRECT.height
        self.tilewidth = self.oceantile.get_width()
    self.tileheight = self.oceantile.get_height()
    print self.tilewidth, self.tileheight
        self.counter = 0
        self.counter2 = 0
    self.ocean = pygame.Surface((w+self.tilewidth,h)).convert()
        for x in range(w/self.tilewidth):
            for y in range(h/self.tileheight):
                self.ocean.blit(self.oceantile, (x*self.tilewidth, y*self.tileheight))
    def left(self):
        self.counter = (self.counter - self.speed) % self.tilewidth
    def right(self):
        self.counter = (self.counter + self.speed) % self.tilewidth
    def up(self):
        if self.counter2 > 0: self.counter2 = (self.counter2 - self.speed) % self.tileheight
    def down(self):
        if self.counter2 < 1140: self.counter2 = (self.counter2 + self.speed) % self.tileheight
screen.blit(arena.map, (0, 0), (arena.counter, arena.counter2, SCREENRECT.width, SCREENRECT.height))
```

I then used the blit function to draw the map, with x and y pixels shaved off via the area input.

`blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect`

```
screen.blit(arena.map, (0, 0), (arena.counter, arena.counter2, SCREENRECT.width, SCREENRECT.height)).
```

Currently I control the scrolling of the mouse with the keyboard, but the grab and drag functionality shouldn't be to hard to figure out with the pygame modules.

Answer (score 0):

*(actually, you are asking 2 different, not very precise questions)*

1. scroll forever: Independent from python a common approach is to
   mirror the images at the edges so you can implement a virtually
   endless world from 1 or some images (tiles of the map).
2. GUI framework/API: From my experience Qt (so in your case maybe PyQt) is
   well documented and designed to quite easily realize OS independent
   GUI.